# iOS Rich Notifications multiple attachments (iOS 10+)

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

How are multiple attachments handled in the UNMutableNotificationContent?

Per the apple developer [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unmutablenotificationcontent/1649857-attachments), I added multiple attachments to UNMutableNotificationContent.attachments, however only one of the media attachments appears with the notification after the NotificationService is triggered.

Is there a way to get the other attachments to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like multiple attachments still don't work (on iOS 14). Only the first attachment is displayed in either the basic notification (e.g. on the lock screen) or in the notification detail (e.g. after a long press).

So to display multiple attachments in notification detail one needs to implement a custom interface using Notification Content Extension.